# Azure B2C and multil tenant - Best practices to implement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-b2c, multi-tenant

Technical Stack

- Asp.Net MVC
- API
- Azure B2C

We have configured B2C with WebApp & WebApi.

We need to have Azure B2C login page when user click on below link

http(s)://mydomain.com/$tenantAlias

So that means, based on tenantID, we need to configure tenant address, client ID for correct login page for signin page.

In single tenant, we set up configure(app) in startup.cs, so in this case, we need to read url in startup.cs file itself and then get the configuration values accordingly.

Now, same way we need to implement in API, so will pass tenant ID in header from MVC, so how to read headers in startup.cs file?

Is this the right way to implement Azure B2C multi tenant?

Answer (score 1):

You can see how I added multiple trusted token issuers in a .Net API here:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/blob/master/apps/spa-hellojs/source-code/.Net-Core-API-RBAC/MultiBearerAPI/Startup.cs#L35

In this example i trust tokens from an AAD tenant, and an AAD B2C tenant.

Comment: in our case, we have B2C multi tenant, so how to manage it within source code is a question and what are the best practices. We found many examples with single tenant where implementation is in startup.cs file

Comment: You need to explain what `b2c multi tenant` means. One other way is an API Gateway with multiple trusted token issuers, and then it uses a single token to talk to the back end APIs.